# What was the marking that Prophet Velen transferred to Yrel? (Spoilers)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The cutscene in question is this one:

After you battled Ner'zhul, he summons the Dark Star to destroy the Draenei. During the summoning, Velen transfers a magical marking from his face to that of Yrel. What was this marking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marking itself is known as a forehead signet - the symbol appears above the forehead of a Draenei when casting the self-heal '[Gift of the Naaru](http://wowpedia.org/Gift_of_the_Naaru)'.

Unfortunately I'm unable to find any specific lore on the relevance or purpose of this sigil (beyond its association to the spell). There's [an interpretation](http://fyre.it/GFoZ1j.4) that the passing of this symbol from Velen to Yrel may have signified transference of leadership of the Draenei, but I can't find an alternative source to verify this.

Comment: And when you later see Yrel, she no longer has the signet...

Comment: Pure speculation, but the impression I get is that it's something a Draenei can toggle at will - so maybe she'd only have it 'on' at, I don't know, parties, state affairs etc, much like a monarch's crown.

Answer (score 0):

The mark on her forehead is a sigil, or the mark that all draenei can apply to their own heads or other players for a healing buff, a good draenei knows how to get around the 10% drain Blizz gave us a few years ago after the other faction whined enough about it, we just apply it at the start of a fight and it buffs at 20% of that level and not when near death. Hers is different in that it is larger and brighter, signifying that it has some greater meaning that is yet to be revealed...and yes, she will be the new prophet...Blizz said so awhile back.

Comment: Good answer, but if you could add a link to the official Blizzard announcement on this it'd be a great one.